# Get return value of a class function in php

Tags: php, function, class

I am trying get return value that defined in included file's class function, I am able to run function but not able to get return value from function -

Here is my code  -

```
class A extends B {
    protected $input; 
    protected $output;

    function test($c){
        $data[] = $c; 
        return $data;   
    }   
}


include "../myfile.php"; 

function myfunc(){
    
    $obj = new A; 
    $returnData = $obj->test("myData");
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($returnData); 
}
```

When I am executing function `myfunc()`, it is executing, but not getting data that return by `test` function of included file's class.

I checked some similiar questions but my code is not running.

Comment: It works: https://3v4l.org/onPW5

Comment: Is class `A` in `myfile.php`?  Where is class `B`?

Comment: Works fine for me.  Are there any errors in your PHP logs?  What's in `myfile.php`?  Where do you execute `myfunc()`?  Where do you define `B`?  Please provide a minimal example which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: _For Clarity_ A Class Function is called a Method

Comment: Try `echo "<pre>" . print_r($returnData,1) . "</pre>";`

Comment: Probably turn on error reporting. https://3v4l.org/JJkqk

Comment: Might be Some error, concept is ryt...Thank you guys